# How to pass JSONArray in android multipart image upload

Tags: android, multipart

I want to pass arrayList values "tags" and "category" in multipart image upload

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        QuestionPicArray = params[0];
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(UrlLinks.base_url + "/api/forum/create");
        httpPost.addHeader(Constants.AUTHORIZATION, sp.getToken(context));
        httpPost.addHeader(Constants.contentType, "image/jpeg");

        org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity entity = new org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        for (int i = 0; i < QuestionPicArray.size(); i++) {
            File sourceFile = new File(QuestionPicArray.get(i).toString());

            entity.addPart("file[" + i + "]", new FileBody(sourceFile));

            entity.addPart("title", new StringBody( title.toString()));
            entity.addPart("desc", new StringBody( desc.toString()));
            entity.addPart("askedTo",new StringBody( askedTo.toString()));
            if (!askedTo.equalsIgnoreCase("open"))
            entity.addPart("anaonFlag",new StringBody(anaonFlag.toString()));


            for(int j=0;j<tags.size();j++)
            {
                //  Array
                entity.addPart("tags",new StringBody(String.valueOf(tags.get(j)), Charset.forName("EUC-KR")));

            }
            for(int j=0;j<category.size();j++)
            {
                //  Array
                entity.addPart("category",new StringBody(String.valueOf(category.get(j)), Charset.forName("EUC-KR")));

            }


        }

        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        // Making server call
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
        getData = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
```

and I am getting "result Error: Not Found" as result

Please suggest me how to pass values of arrayList in addPart() of MultipartEntity

Comment: @ppreerika have you solver it??

Answer (score 0):

It's my pleasure to answer your question.

```
if(result.contains("{")||result.contains("[")){
    // pass JSON data
} else {
    //  Dealing with errors
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: what does result means here?

Comment: return is **Not Found**, and i have to pass arrayList value in  addPart() of MultipartEntity object. how will i do that?

Comment: I understand.

You want take the ```ArrayList``` as ```value```.

We also convert value to JSON.

Then as value parameters.

I use Gson


 `public static MultipartEntity convert(List<String> parameters) {
        entity.put("tags",new Gson().toJson(parameters));
        return entity;
    }`


You can try.